# Trying to Implement a priority queue in a different way

Tags: java, priority-queue

I am trying to implement a priority queue which functions a little bit different than normal priority queue.Here,the idea is to support fast insert, but slower access to the highest priority item. Insert method in this case places the new item wherever it is convenient;remove and peek methods must thus search through the entire queue for the highest priority item.

```
public class MinPriorityQueue {

/** Constructs a new MinPriorityQueue with capacity cap and size 0.
 * 
 * @param cap Capacity of the new queue.
 */
public MinPriorityQueue(int cap) {         

    this.queue = (Comparable []) new Comparable[cap];
    this.size = 0;
    this.cap = cap;
}

int size() {
   return this.size;
}

int capacity() {
   return this.cap;
}

 boolean isEmpty() {
   return this.size==0;
}

boolean isFull() {
    return this.size == cap;       
}

void insert(Comparable e) {
    if (this.size == cap) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    queue[size] = e;
    size++;



Comparable remove() {

    if (this.size == 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    int maxIndex = 0;
    for (int i=1; i<size; i++) { 
        if (queue[i].compareTo (queue[maxIndex]) < 0) { 
            maxIndex = i; 
        } 
    } 
    Comparable result = queue[maxIndex]; 
    size--; 
    queue[maxIndex] = queue[size]; 
    return result;
    }


 /** Returns, but does not remove, the lowest-priority item in the
 * queue.
 * 
 * Complexity: O(n)
 * @return Lowest priority item.
 * @throws IllegalStateException if the queue is empty.
 */
Comparable top()  {
           if (this.size == 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
         /*  int i;
           for (i=0; i < size; i++) {
        if (queue[i].compareTo (size-1) < 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
           return queue[size - 1];*/
    return  queue[size-1]; 
  }



Comparable[] queue; // Contents of the queue

private  int cap;
private int size;    

}
```

//// Test File

```
 /**
     * Test of remove method, of class MinPriorityQueue.
     */
    @Test
    public void testRemove() {
    System.out.println("remove");
    MinPriorityQueue q = new MinPriorityQueue(10);

    boolean throws_exception = false;
    try {
        q.remove();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        throws_exception = true;
    } catch (Throwable e) {

    }
    assertTrue("remove throws an exception when empty", throws_exception);

    // Permutation of 0...9
    int[] input = {0, 5, 9, 2, 3, 1, 6, 8, 7, 4};

    for (int i : input) {
        q.insert(i);
    }

    assertTrue(q.isFull());

    for (int i = 10; i > 0; --i) {
        assertEquals(q.size(), i);
        Integer x = (Integer) q.remove();
        assertEquals(x, new Integer(10 - i)); // Items are removed in correct order            
    }

    assertTrue(q.isEmpty());
}

/**
 * Test of top method, of class MinPriorityQueue.
 */
@Test
public void testTop() {
    System.out.println("top");
    MinPriorityQueue q = new MinPriorityQueue(10);

    boolean throws_exception = false;
    try {
        q.top();
    } catch (IllegalStateException x) {
        throws_exception = true;
    } catch (Throwable x) {

    }
    assertTrue("top throws an exception when empty", throws_exception);

    int[] input = {0, 5, 9, 2, 3, 1, 6, 8, 7, 4};
    int smallest = 10;
    for (int i : input) {
        q.insert(i);
        if (i < smallest) {
            smallest = i;
        }

        assertEquals(q.top(), smallest);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        assertEquals(q.top(), i);
        q.remove();
    }
}
```

I have been able to implement all methods except remove and peek because i am unable to get the logic right to implement the methods.I am unable to figure out how we can search the entire queue to find the highest priority item.For this,i believe for loop should be used,but just not getting the logic right

EDIT : I am able to get the logic right for remove() method,just need to get the pop() method to work

Comment: With remove you are simply decreasing the size of the array even though the item being removed is not at the end of the array

Comment: Ya.I was trying different stuff to get the logic right.Can u guide me on how to make it right .Thanks

Comment: @  Scary Wombat .I figured the logic for remove method and updated my post.Just need to get the pop() method to work

Comment: Side notes: the cast `(Comparable []) new Comparable[cap];` is unnecessary. `queue[maxIndex] = queue[size];` should happen before `size--`, otherwise you'd duplicate the next to last element and "remove" the last as well.

Comment: Another one: Using just `Comparable` is dangerous because you could add incompatible types (try comparing a string and a date for example). Besides that, those elements don't have a _priority_ so you'll probably either want to use generics to use a more concrete type or provide a priority along with the data and use a specialized class for the elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to use a `java.util.List` instead of an `array`. So the `List` will keep the elements in the queue and handle the positioning of them without sorting them (so it still uses a fast insert). If you use the implementation `java.util.ArrayList` for the `List` interface it uses an `array` internally so it's almost exactly what you were trying but easier, because someone else has already done most of the work...

So you could implement the class `MinPriorityQueue` like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

//use a generic type argument T here that extends comparable so you can only store objects of a specific type that are comparable to each other
public class MinPriorityQueue<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    private List<T> queue; // Contents of the queue

    private int cap;
    //private int size;

    /**
     * Constructs a new MinPriorityQueue with capacity cap and size 0.
     * 
     * @param cap
     *        Capacity of the new queue.
     */
    public MinPriorityQueue(int cap) {
        this.queue = new ArrayList<T>(cap);
        //this.size = 0;
        this.cap = cap;
    }

    public int size() {
        //return this.size;
        return queue.size();
    }

    public int capacity() {
        return this.cap;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        //return this.size == 0;
        return queue.isEmpty();
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        //return this.size == cap;
        return queue.size() == cap;
    }

    public void insert(T e) {
        if (queue.size() == cap) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        //queue[size] = e;
        //size++;
        queue.add(e);
    }

    /**
     * Removes and returns the lowest-priority item from the queue.
     * 
     * Complexity: O(n)
     * 
     * @return Lowest priority item that was in the queue.
     * @throws IllegalStateException
     *         if the queue is empty.
     */
    public Comparable<T> remove() {
        if (queue.size() == 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }

        /*for (int i = 0; i < this.size; i++) {
            if (this.queue[i] == queue[size]) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return queue[--size];*/

        //initialize the lowest priority item with the first one in the list
        int lowestPriorityIndex = 0;

        //search every other item in the list to see whether it has a lower priority than the current lowest priority 
        for (int i = 1; i < queue.size(); i++) {
            if (queue.get(i).compareTo(queue.get(lowestPriorityIndex)) < 0) {
                lowestPriorityIndex = i;
            }
        }

        //return and remove the lowest priority item
        return queue.remove(lowestPriorityIndex);
    }

    /**
     * Returns, but does not remove, the lowest-priority item in the queue.
     * 
     * Complexity: O(n)
     * 
     * @return Lowest priority item.
     * @throws IllegalStateException
     *         if the queue is empty.
     */
    public Comparable<T> top() {
        if (queue.size() == 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        /*  int i;
          for (i=0; i < size; i++) {
        if (queue[i].compareTo (size-1) < 0) {
           break;
        }
        }
          return queue[size - 1];*/


        //initialize the lowest priority item with the first one in the list
        int lowestPriorityIndex = 0;

        //search every other item in the list to see whether it has a lower priority than the current lowest priority 
        for (int i = 1; i < queue.size(); i++) {
            if (queue.get(i).compareTo(queue.get(lowestPriorityIndex)) < 0) {
                lowestPriorityIndex = i;
            }
        }

        //return (but not remove) the lowest priority item
        return queue.get(lowestPriorityIndex);
    }
}
```

This code passes all of the test cases you provided in your question.

I also added a generic type argument in the example code (therefore the class declaration is now `MinPriorityQueue<T extends Comparable<T>>`), because it was needed to actually compare the elements. You can check about generic types [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).

Comment: No.I can't use List.But i implemented your methods in array and it works.Thank You